# GNU ARM Eclipse: troubles with openocd debug

Tags: eclipse, arm

I'm trying to use Eclipse with GNU ARM plugins to debug my stm32f4-discovery board, however, still no luck. The same board works perfectly in Keil running in the virtual machine, so, it doesn't seem to be hardware problem.

I use Linux Mint 13, I've installed all the prerequisites, I have created templated hello world project, it compiles, and when I try to start debug, it stops at the step "Configuring GDB", and after a couple of seconds it fails with the following:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333

Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Connection timed out.
localhost:3333: Connection timed out.
```

Then I tried to manually start `openocd`:

```
$ openocd -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/board/stm32f4discovery.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.7.0 (2014-11-08-01:25)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : This adapter doesn't support configurable speed
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v23 API v2 SWIM v0 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : Target voltage: 2.918263
Info : stm32f4x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
```

And `arm-none-eabi-gdb`:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gdb ~/projects/test_stm/arm_c_1/Debug/arm_c_1.elf
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 7.6.0.20140731-cvs
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/dimon/projects/test_stm/arm_c_1/Debug/arm_c_1.elf...done.
(gdb) target remote localhost:3333
Remote debugging using localhost:3333
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Then, `openocd` said that connection is accepted:

```
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection from 3333
Info : stm32f4x errata detected - fixing incorrect MCU_IDCODE
Info : device id = 0x10006413
Info : flash size = 1024kbytes
Warn : acknowledgment received, but no packet pending
undefined debug reason 6 - target needs reset
```

But, when started by Eclipse, it doesn't work, for some reason.

Well, then I tried to keep `openocd` started manually and alter my Debug configuration: at the "Debugger" tab, I've unchecked "Start OpenOCD locally". Now, debug session a kind of starts: debug perspective is opened, no meaningful errors are echoed, but debug buttons (resume, suspend, etc) remain inactive. The chip isn't even reprogrammed: previous firmware programmed from inside Keil keeps flashing LEDs.

Here's a screenshot of what Eclipse looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30k7N.png

Output of openocd:

```
$ /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/board openocd -f ./stm32f4discovery.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.7.0 (2014-11-08-01:25)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : This adapter doesn't support configurable speed
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v23 API v2 SWIM v0 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : Target voltage: 2.919691
Info : stm32f4x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection from 3333
Info : stm32f4x errata detected - fixing incorrect MCU_IDCODE
Info : device id = 0x10006413
Info : flash size = 1024kbytes
Warn : acknowledgment received, but no packet pending
undefined debug reason 6 - target needs reset
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000154 msp: 0x20030000
semihosting is enabled
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000154 msp: 0x20030000, semihosting
```

I even tried to re-install all the Eclipse plugins as well as `openocd`, nothing helped. What could be the trouble?

Comment: I'm not using these plugins you mention, but just the "normal" GDB Hardware Debugging" plugin from Eclipse (it is available in "standard" Eclipse plugin repositories). It's true that you have to configure it (which takes me like 15 seconds, because there are maybe 5 options to enter), but it _never_ causes me any trouble... That's why I really don't know what's the point of using these GNU ARM Eclipse plugins, the configurations are almost identical anyway, so no effort is saved...

Comment: Current OpenOCD at this time is is `0.8.0`, please update - it may fix your problem.